# Get Country Code according to first IP (Maxming), Getting two IP

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.3, maxmind

I am using maxmind module in nginx to get country code of visiters IP. Below are my some configuration part of nginx.config file,

```
geoip_country /etc/nginx/geo_ip/GeoIP.dat;
location ~ \.php$ {
    root /home/app;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
}
```

In php **$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']**, I am getting 2 (two) IPs and these are comma separated. So nginx maxmind module giving me country code according to second IP. So I want to get country Code according to first IP. Can anyone please help me in this issue?